# Indexing in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

1- Is it a good idea to index boolean fields in MongoDB?

2- Suppose I have a user collection, and I am inserting 1000 documents in it. After this insertion phase, I create indexes on some fields.

So, I want to ask "Will these indexes work for already created documents or not?"

Comment: What exactly is not already answered for you here - [Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)?

Comment: @Neil you marked it as a duplicate.  but still, there is no such answer for my both questions.

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate to the very basic point that it points to the documentation. 1 - *"Is it a good idea"* - Read the documentation and don't ask for opinions. Would have closed your question for that alone. 2 - *".. after insertion I will create..."* - Read the documentation, as we actually recommend that. And talking about why would be too-broad and another close reason. We told you where the documentation is, so please go and learn something.